# Backup and restore data in the cloud - appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, restore, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I would like to know how people tackle backup and restore of data in the cloud.
I plan to use AppEngine for business use and as far as I can tell there is no classic backup and restore functionality built into AppEngine. It is reasonable because there database structure is much different.

So the question is how to approach backup and restore in high replication AppEngine application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with the previous posts. The built-in datastore backup / restore is solid enough.

However, if your data is partioned by namespace, Google does not offer the possibility to backup / restore by namespace which is a big limitation. It means that if you have a multi-tenant application, you cannot backup / restore data for one namespace.

Would you really need backup / restore by namespace, you will have to extend the backup / restore from Google which is open source (see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py).

I am currently on the path to perform this modification to the open source of Google but did not find the time to do it yet.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I do plan to use multi tenant. That is one of the major factor of choosing GAE. I guess I have to learn the python backup/restore script now. Thank you.

Comment: Ido, by when do you plan to use backup / restore by namespace ? I should be working on it during the summer. Will let you know the status of my work. Having said this, I suspect that Google will deliver a solution for this one pretty soon. If you can afford to wait for the standard solution, it would be better so you would have a standard solution.

Comment: I except to need it in the next few month. I'll be glad to have some way to be notify about your work.

Comment: Hi Ido, I have received a consulting offer to develop the solution and  to decrease the cost, I am trying to see who would be interested to buy it. If you are still interested, just check on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517384/datastore-backup-restore-by-namespace-for-300-who-is-willing-to-join

Comment: the following article indicates that backups of a single tenant/namespace are supported: see _namespace_ parameter in [Specifying Backups in a Cron File](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups)

Answer (score 1):

[Backup/Restore, Copy and Delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) on Google App Engine is still experimental, but it is there. I would suggest you to built a prototype and try to Backup/Restore a few times before deciding to build the whole thing. The data is pretty much secure, but if you want to protect the datastore from some abuse/attack then it's necessary to have that resolved. If you are afraid of losing data, then the chances are pretty low for that actually to happen, but still, you never know!

Comment: It's not the losing data part, it's more about how to handle when we did a mistake and want to go back to yesterday or the day before that. With current SQL Server backup I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

GAE backup works pretty well for us: few days ago I backed up entities of about 800MB in size. No problems there. It also does restore - just save data to a file in blobstore or Cloud Store and you can restore it anytime. There is a limitation: no automatic/programmable backup - it's all manual.